# How to change notification text in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

We are sending adaptive cards to bot window of end users.

The notification pop up showing "Sent a card".

We would like to update it with custom message. We are using C# to build the application.

Please refer below snippet, where we tried the "Summary" property. But it did not fix our issue.

```
var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), credentials);
var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(new List<Attachment>() { GetCardAttachment() });
response.Summary = "Custom Message";
await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationId, (Activity)response);
```

Kindly suggest how to update the notification message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change notification text when bot sends an adaptive card in Microsoft Teams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229084/how-to-change-notification-text-when-bot-sends-an-adaptive-card-in-microsoft-tea)

Comment: It is working in browsers. But it is not working in MS Teams

Answer (score 0):

Custom Teams notification can be sent by adding summary as below:

```
 var response = MessageFactory.Text(string.Empty);
 response.Attachments.Add(cardAttachment);
 response.Summary = "Here goes your sample text";
 await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
```

But one deviation we noticed that it works fine in Web client but not in Desktop Teams.
We have raised a bug for this issue and concerned team is looking into it.

Comment: Thanks Prasad.
Could you please confirm whether it is Product behavior or any recent changes in MS Teams product caused this impact?

Comment: It seems to be product behavior